# Octopress site.title not changing?

Tags: html, css, octopress

I created a new blog using Octopress and a theme called Oscailte by coogie. I am having some trouble though. I titled the blog, and all pages are pulling the correct page title except the landing page, which is pulling the default title - - "This is a title for your homepage".

Code in _config.yml:

```
title: TheHopefulWebDev
subtitle: TheHopefulWebDev
author: Joseph Sawyer
simple_search: http://google.com/search
description: TheHopefulWebDev
```

Code in /source/_includes/custom/header.html

```
<div class="grid__item two-fifths lap-four-sixths palm-one-whole">
  <a href="{{ root_url }}/" class="site-title">{{ site.title }}</a>
</div>
```

This displays correctly. So I don't understand why it isn't pulling the correct title for the site itself on the landing page.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT: I should add that the full title it is displaying in the titlebar of the browser is "This is the title for your homepage -- TheHopefulWebDev". Tried deleting the "This is the title.." bit from /_deploy/index.html so it now reads:

```
<title>TheHopefulWebDev</title>
```

Shut server down, restarted using    rake preview, still getting the same title. : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to edit /source/_layouts/default.html with the following at the top:

```
---
title: Main
---
```

Now the titlebar displays "Main - The Hopeful Web Dev"

Hope it helps someone.